# Retrieve header values from post request

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to retrieve values from the header response, but can't seem to retrieve this? i've tried with `allHeaderFields`, but does not seem to be a member of `NSURLResponse`?

```
testProvider.request(.SignIn(email, password), completion: { result in
    switch result {
    case let .Success(response):

        do {
            try response.filterSuccessfulStatusCodes()
            let data = try response.mapJSON()



        }
        catch {
            // show an error to your user
        }

    case let .Failure(error):
        print(error)

        let description = "Error! Please check your internet connection"
        delegate.loginProvider(self, didError: description)
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this closure you can get the received headers with `response?.allHeaderFields`.

```
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
        .response { request, response, data, error in
            print(request?.allHTTPHeaderFields)
            print(response?.allHeaderFields)
            print(data)
            print(error)
    }
```